# How do I recharge five 18650 cells in parallel?

Tags: battery-charging, parallel, tp4056

I have a 5P1S configuration using 18650 cells, embedded in an LED project. I have installed a TP4056 to charge 5 cells in parallel. Now I am realising the TP4056 is for single cell use.
So I don't know whether to install a TP4056 on each cell wired in parallel,
OR, purchase a different charge module which will charge 5 cells in parallel.
Cells are unprotected versions.
TP4056 is the later one, with IN, OUT, and BATT tabs.
Switch is installed so I can recharge without load to project.
I have limited space for multiple TP4056s, so I am leaning towards replacing TP4056 with a larger charge module for charging 5 cells in parallel.
I am having trouble locating such a module. Any help and advice is appreciated, as I am no expert.
In summary, which direction should I head? And what 5P1S charge module should I purchase?

Comment: The calls are permanently connected in parallel?

Comment: Yes 5 cells in parallel.

Comment: 5 cells in parallel is just one single large cell and you can charge it like any other single cell. What is the question actually about?

Comment: It takes just more time for charging ...

Comment: My question is - Do i retain the tp4056 to charge 5 cells?  Or do I purchase a dedicated recharge module for 5 cells?I'm confused as to why I cant use the Tp4056 to charge 5 cells. Is it dangerous? or simply a longer charge time?

Comment: I'm happy if its just a longer charge time. But there's many people advising that the tp4056 is for single cell only.

Comment: There aren't any special 5P1S chargers, just 1S chargers which can accept five times higher capacity. You'd be surprised how many charger IC does not care what so ever about capacity and just keeps on charging until done. Termination current may suffer compared to what's recommended in the datasheet, but I would not worry about 5x.

Comment: Why do they advise on not using tp4056 for multi cells?

Comment: Multiple in parallel should not be an issue. Multiple in series will be complicated though with TP4056.

Comment: It is already said that 5 cells in parallel is one large cell and you can charge it with a charger for one cell. Why do you think you can't use TP4056? Who are "they" that say it can't be used? We don't know why "they" say that.

Comment: I know 5 cells or 100 cells in parallel is one large cell. 'They' refers to the manufacturers. Have you not looked at manufacturers data sheets? It states "For single cell use only"    I'm assuming its a safety issue, or amperage issue, and safety is what I'm concerned about.

Comment: By single, they mean 1S. You have 1S.

Comment: Thanku Winny, that makes sense. I feel comfortable contiuing with the Tp4056 now.